# Semantic HTML for alphabetical list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, semantic-markup

I need to write a simple alphabetical list of words like this:

> A 
>  
>   - Andorra 
>   - Angola 
>   - Antigua and Barbuda 
>   - Argentina
>
> B 
>   - Bahamas 
>   - Bahrain 
>   - Bangladesh 
>   - Barbados

(and so on)

Is it ok to use an ordered list to keep my HTML semantic and then clear the styling using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS doesn’t affect the semantics. You can style an `ol` in any way you want (display it without any list indicator, use bullets instead of numbers, display it in one line, visually hide it, etc.), it keeps being an `ol`, and it keeps its semantics.

Unless the page explicitly says that the entries are sorted alphabetically, using an `ul` instead of an `ol` might be appropriate. `ol` must only be used if a different order would change the meaning.

So if the only indicator of the alphabetical order are the headings ("A", "B" etc.), you could use `ul`:

```html
<section>
  <h2>List of …</h2>

  <section id="a">
    <h3>A</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Andorra</li>
      <li>Angola</li>
    </ul>
  </section>    

  <section id="b">
    <h3>B</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Bahamas</li>
      <li>Bahrain</li>
    </ul>
  </section>    

</section>
```

However, one could argue that a heading like "A" implies that the entries are sorted alphabetically (instead of just *starting* with an "A"). In that case, `ol` should be used.